# Combine multiple Map<String,List> structs by joining lists with keys of the same name

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8

What would be the cleanest way to do this?

I have

```
Map<String, List<String>> map1 = ...;  
Map<String, List<String>> map2 = ...; 
Map<String, List<String>> map3 = ...;
```

The maps all have the exact same keys, and no duplicate values. I want to append the Lists of map2 and map3 to the end of the list of map1, for each key.

This is how I am currently trying to do it:

```
Map<String, List<String>> conversions = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> histList = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String key : map1.keySet()){
    histList.addAll(map1.get(key));
    histList.addAll(map2.get(key));
    histList.addAll(map3.get(key));
    conversions.put(key,histList);
}
```

Comment: Your code would work if you declared `histList` inside the loop so you get a new list each time.

Comment: @LouisWasserman good catch. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to make a temporary list, you could directly add to list one, instead of replacing it.

```
for (String key: map1.keySet()) { //iterate over all the keys
    map1.get(key).addAll(map2.get(key)); //add all the values in map 2 to map 1
    map1.get(key).addAll(map3.get(key)); //add all the values in map 3 to map 1
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Nice and clean.

Comment: Iterating over the keys to perform a map lookup (on the same map) is an unnecessary waste of resource and you are even performing the lookup *twice*. You can simply iterate over the `entrySet()` instead, to get both, key and value without map lookups. You can do it more concise using `map1.forEach( (key,value) -> { value.addAll(map2.get(key)); value.addAll(map3.get(key)); });`